How to get random number in text editor using vscode user snippet?
I am trying to make a keyboard shortcut in VS Code that will give me a random number from 1-100 when I use it.
This is currently the VS Code snippet I have. However, when I use it, it gives me the text that's in the body.
Is it possible to make it give me a random number 1 to 100 instead?
  "Print to console": {
    "prefix": "makerandomnumber",
    "body": [
        "Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;"
    ],
    "description": "Generate a random number"
}


FWIW, that's not really what snippets are for. They're meant to be more static, like templates, and they only support a few dynamic features. This might still be possible, but it's a bit odd is all, and it might be easier to use a keybinding directly (without a snippet).

Perhaps this VS Code extension can fulfill your needs: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jrebocho.vscode-random. I don't know how convenient it will be to use, but one of the options it provides is called "extension.randomIntCustomRange : Random integer (custom range) - Generates a random integer within a given custom range". Maybe you can bind a shortcut key to that option.

A couple of thoughts: an extension I wrote can easily do what you want because it can run your javascript.  Find and Transform.
Make this keybinding:

{
  "key": "alt+q",           // whatever you want
  "command": "findInCurrentFile",
  "args" : {
      "description": "Insert a random number between 1 - 100",
      "replace": [
        "$${",
          "return Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;",
        "}$$",
      ],
      "restrictFind": "selections",
      "postCommands": "cancelSelection"
  }
}

You'll notice that is a keybinding and not a snippet (although I have done some work in "snippefying" the extension).

You can get close using vscode's built-in snippet variables.  See this snippet:
"random": {
  "prefix": "makerandomnumber",
  "body": "${RANDOM/\\d{4}(\\d{2})/$1/}"  // 00-99
},

${RANDOM} produces a 6-digit random number.  The snippet then only uses the last 2 digits.  I assume this would produce a number from 00-99, so perhaps not ideal for your use case.

Here is a snippet that I think does close to what you want:
    "Get Random Number1":
    {
        "prefix": "getRandy"
        ,"body": "${RANDOM}"
        ,"description": "Get a random 6 digit number."
    }

We can customize it further, as a previous answer noted, to only return 2 digits.
    "Get Random Number1":
    {
        "prefix": "getRandy"
        ,"body": "${RANDOM}"
        ,"description": "Get a random 6 digit number."
    }
    ,"Get Random Number2":
    {
        "prefix": "getRandy2"
        ,"body": "${RANDOM/(\\d{2}).*/$1/}"
        ,"description": "Get a random 2 digit number."
    }

You can see that we can use a regex to capture the first two digits of the random 6 digit number that ${RANDOM} gives you and then we only return those first two captured digits.

(\\d{2}) = captures the first two digits into regex group1
.* = captures the rest of the digits. ie. the last 4.
$1 = Inserts regex group1 as the final output.

To see what other variables you can use in VSCode snippets see reference:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_variables
Note: You can not use javascript in the snippet body.
reference: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets
